# How to install Android Studio's components manually with no emulator?

Tags: android-studio

I have downloaded the Android Studio from internet. But after installation when I opens the Android studio, then it asks for downloading some large components. And my internet speed is slow, so it is not installing and getting stuck. So, **is there a way that I can download those components manually? And also I don't want Android emulator to be installed because I have turned usb debugging on in my phone.**

Comment: You will get asked during the installation process if you want to download an emulator so that is not the problem. However i do not see a way how to download the components with such a slow connection. If android studio gets a timeout, then I exspect that every other software will too. But anyway you should post the error message that android studio is giving you, after it cancels the download. Otherwise we can not be completly sure what the problem is.

Comment: @user11670196 it is not giving any error but while downloading components, it is just stuck and not progressing

Comment: Then I thinkt the only solution is running it for a really long time, so it can download everything. Because it does not really matter which tool you use, it will always take for ever

Comment: it's likely op wants a resumable download option. however, it's not clear if the Android studio provides that. it may be that the studio restarts a large download if it gets interrupted in between. a third-party download may take forever but it can be resumed to finish eventually.